# How to design a chatbot that pops-up on a website using microsoft bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to create a chatbot using C# that initiates the conversation with the user using microsoft bot framework, my question is how do I make a chatbot that pops up in the bottom right side of the website? so far what I have done is that I created a FormFlow that will interact with the user. based from my research I should use the webchat control of bot framework but i do not know how to embed the web chat control to the website. I apologize for my newbie question, I am new in bot framework.

Comment: Take a look at the [WebChat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) as a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides @NathanBlaine mentioned, leveging the `iframe` to embed the webchat bot.

> chatbot that pops up in the bottom right side of the website

A simplest method to achieve your requirement, you can create a button in your website, bind a javascript function to this button, to open a new browser window with the bot's embed endpoint:

```
window.open("https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/<your_bot_applition>?s=YOUR_SECRET_KEY", "_blank", "width=200,height=400");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Azure you can go to your bot service > channels > web chat and then find an embed code that looks like

```
<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/YOUR_SERVICE?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'></iframe>
```

There are ways to customize this iframe (with a bit of googling). Using JS you could have a window with the embedded iframe popup after some time.

Comment: Thank you for advice, I was able to create the web chat using the iframe in Azure bot service.